# Visual Studio 2017 C# target framework issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I recently included a .net 4.6.2 project to use with my .net core 2.1 app. But after I've done this the projects stopped to compile throwing this error:

> Error     Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" in the
>   "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.  SelfSignCertificateAssistant

The project stopped to compile even for another pure 4.6.2 solution. Needless to say it was working just fine before.

There was absolutely nothing that was changed in the project, so I'm not sure how to fix this:

[image]

Comment: Did you run `nuget restore` after setting the target framework?

Comment: That error message promises too much.  You can't use a .NETFramework assembly in a .NETCore project.  It has to be rebuilt to target either .NETCore or .NETStandard.

Answer (score 3):

As i figured in most cases solution proposed by @Chris should work. But for some unknown reason my Visual Studio just refused to compile it throwing the same error. I tried to re-download the project, re-reference frameworks, restarting VS...

What helped me is physically deleting project folder and **then** re-downloading it from source control. After this was done i was able to successfully compile it. Not sure what was the problem though.

Comment: I had the same problem. Your comment helped a lot. I just replaced the obj and bin folders with a backup.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio go to **Tools > Options...** and in the left pane, scroll down and select **Nuget Package Manager**. Then, check the boxes under **General** that say "**Allow nuget to download missing packages**" and "**Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio**".

Once you do that, try **rebuild**ing your project and nuget should then restore any missing packages for your project.

Comment: I did all of the above, and cleared nuget cache but that did not help. And what confuses me, it does not compile even within other non-.netCore solutions

Comment: I restarted the VisualStudio, re-downloaded project from TFS(with overwrite option), even restarted my PC... no luck, still getting this error